# How to include paragraph break in command argument?

Tags: spacing, macros, robust-commands

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{3pt}

\begin{document}

Here is the first paragraph.

Here is the second.

\newcommand*{\testing}[1]{#1}

\testing{\par Here is the third.\par Here is the fourth.}

\end{document}
```

The output looks correct in this case:

[image]

However, I have a compiler error:

```
Runaway argument?

! Paragraph ended before \testing was complete
```

I've tried using `\\\\` instead of `\par`, but it creates incorrect space between the paragraphs.

How can I define multiple paragraphs in a command argument and have it come out formatted just as though I had typed those paragraphs in directly?

Comment: Have you tried with `\newcommand{\testing}[1]{#1}` (no star)?

Comment: @Kurt Oh, damn - I forgot to try that. And indeed it works. Thanks!

Comment: I have to wonder, what did you want the `*` to do?

Comment: If a macro is **not** defined in terms of `\long`, the token `\par` is not allowed inside that macro's arguments—this is regardless `\par`'s meaning/regardless `\par`'s definition. `\newcommand*`, i.e., the starred variant, tells LaTeX explicitly to define the command not in terms of `\long`. As the `\long`-mechanism is only about the token `\par` itself and not about meanings of whatsoever tokens you can do: `\testing{\csname par\endcsname Here is the third.\csname par\endcsname Here is the fourth.}` or `\let\parcopy=\par \testing{\parcopy Here is the third.\parcopy Here is the fourth.}`

Answer (score 2):

Command `\newcommand*{\testing}[1]{#1}` (the starred version!) does simply not allow an `\par` in code `#1`.

If you need `\par` use command `\newcommand{\testing}[1]{#1}` (no star) instead, it is defined to allow `\par`s ...

See the corrected code

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{3pt}

\begin{document}

Here is the first paragraph.

Here is the second.

\newcommand{\testing}[1]{#1} % <======================================== no star

\testing{\par Here is the third.\par Here is the fourth.}

\end{document}
```

and its with no errors compiled result:

[image: resulting pdf]